# Using scope variables to change other scope variables Angular 1.0 vs 1.2

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change the font style on some elements via a settings menu in Angular. 
When using a scope variable to change a value in another scope variable, the changes don't proagate instantly but first after the next change.

This don't work: http://jsfiddle.net/VRQH8/11/ (but it work in 1.1)

But this does: http://jsfiddle.net/VRQH8/12/

How come the `fontColor` is shown as the correct (new) value in the first jsFiddle but `font` won't update until the next change?

I was using the first approach when using Angular 1.0.7, but when switching to 1.2 i noticed that it wont work any more.
Is the second approach better practice (in 1.2) or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ng-click` to an `ng-change`.

```
 ng-change="applyFontColor()"
```

See this working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/VRQH8/14/

The reason why it wasn't working as you expected was because the ng-click event was firing before the model value was actually changed.  The ng-change event fires after the model value is actually changed and is the real behavior that you want (because there can be other ways to change the value of the radio button besides actually "clicking" on it).

Comment: There must have been a change that affects the order of how the ngClick and the ngModel/$watch events are fired with 1.2.  I tried to find the actual change but I couldn't find it after looking for a few minutes.  If you want, take a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and see if you can figure it out